# Redeploying war file(jsp,js) does not update on server

Tags: javascript, jsp, tomcat

I'm working Web Application using spring. I deployed to test the application is running on server used tomcat manager.
And i found the error in my jsp, js code so redeployed the edited new war file(same path, same project name)

But, the problem is occurring here. open the web site the code is not reflected.(checked chrome press F12) This is old code.

But, open the code in server computer the code is changed!!  I don't know what should i do

I already did

1) Disable cache, clear cache in chrome

2) Undeploy old war before deploy the new war

3) Delete the cache file in here

> CATALINA_HOME/work/Catalina/localhost/contentName/org/apache/jsp

I already look around the similar question in stackoverflow. I've got the above solution in another questions But, still problem...

please anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps to clean tomcat your from webapp :

> 1.Undeploy your webapp
>
> 2.Remove everything inside CATALINA_HOME/work/Catalina/localhost
>
> 3.Remove everything inside CATALINA_HOME/temp

If after this still the file changes are not reflected go to ( this is for google chrome smth similar must be for other browsers) browser setting under `Clear Browser Data` select `Remove cached files`

Comment: still not working..
But! maybe i can find the reason. I think the server running the file in webapps/ROOT directory. My application name 'SF'
I deployed my application to new path directory(/SF) not in ROOT. So there are two folders

Comment: webapps/ ROOT and webapps/SF
but, i already changed server.xml file append 'docBase = "SF" path="/SF" is it wrong? If tomcat first look for ROOT directory and then they are looking for docBase??

Comment: I solve this problem! The reason is context path is wrong
my domains is "www.abc.com/blabla" the context isn't starting 'SF'!! 
So, i changed the path="/" like this. and then source code is updated
thank you for your kindness and time : )